# npm runs dev and npm runs watch error in laravel vue.js

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, vue.js

**npm runs dev and npm runs watch error this** 
Sombody can help me ?

> node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

```
sh: 1: node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-40-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/miftah/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/home/miftah/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ dev: `node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/saranabelanja/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your project specific NodeJS modules:

- Deleting node_modules directory `rm -r node_modules` and
  package-lock.json `rm package-lock.json`
- Reinstalling packages `npm install` (using package.json)

  - When you don't have a package.json, you have to know what to reinstall and install them one by one. You may use options --save and --save-dev in the future...

When working with Docker and steps above fail, you may also try one of these:

- Rebuilding docker container
- Restarting Docker
- Restarting Windows